# Offline codebase browser for Android

Tags: android, programming, source-code

I have the source code of a large application written in Java that I need to understand. I would like to be able to browse through the source code while in public transport to make better use of that time and learn the codebase faster.

I only have an Android phone and tablet as mobile devices. I'm looking for some offline codebase browser for Android. It would be nice if it were like a full IDE able to jump to references, definitions etc. but at the very least, it should display a tree view of the project, do syntax highlighting and work without internet access.

The best I've been able to come up with was to generate documentation including source code via Doxygen and then browse the HTML pages via a browser but that would require me to set up Doxygen correctly and the resulting web would not be friendly to use.

Comment: Any luck? I'm looking for the Python version :)

Comment: @dg123 No luck, sorry.